# How to save GroupedDataset to parquet or convert it to toDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-dataset

I am using spark 1.6.1.

Is there any API available for saving GroupDataset to parquet file.
Or convert it to DataFrame.

E.g. I have a custom Object 'Procedure', I have converted Dataframe to Procedure Object.
After that I am doing group by on patientID.
I wanted to groupdDs to parquet file or pass this as a Dataframe to other function.
I didn't get any API for storage or convert it into Dataframe.

```
val procedureDs: Dataset[Procedure] = joinDf.select("patientid", "patientprocedureid", "procedurecode").as[Procedure]
val groupedDs:GroupedDataset[Long, Procedure] = procedureDs.groupBy{ x => x.patientid }
```

After applying mapGroups

```
val a = groupedDs.mapGroups{ case (k,vs) => { (k, vs.toSeq)}}
```

It gives below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for com.....PatientDiagnosis
- array element class: "com....PatientDiagnosis"
- field (class: "scala.collection.Seq", name: "_2")
- root class: "scala.Tuple2"
```

I had tried to give explicit Encoder

```
val a = groupedDigDs.mapGroups((k,vs) =>  (k, vs.toSeq))(org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.bean(classOf[(Long, Seq[com....PatientDiagnosis])]))
```

Then Error changed to :

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot infer type for class scala.Tuple2 because it is not bean-compliant
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as `GroupedData` (`RelationalGroupedDataset` in Spark 2.x), `GroupedDataset` (`KeyValueGroupedDataset` in Spark 2.x) has to be aggregated before it can saved.

If your goal is to yet another `groupByKey` you can use `mapGroups`:

```
val groupedDs: GroupedDataset[K, V] = ???
// ... { case (k, xs) => (k, xs.toSeq) }  to preserve key as well
groupedDs.mapGroups { case (_, xs) => xs.toSeq }
```

and write the result.